# C++: unique_ptr with unknow deleter

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, unique-ptr

I need to write a function to retrieve and process some data. This data may be allocated in several ways (on the data segment, on the heap, on a shared memory segment and so on):

```
T *data;
if( global ) data = &d;
if( heap )   data = new T [ size ];
if( shm )    data = (T*) shmat( id, 0, 0 );
// processing data ...
```

Since `data` may be dynamically allocated, I'd think that the best way to handle it is using an `unique_ptr` or some other kind of smart pointers. However it's not always dynamically allocated: I'd need to choose at runtime the deleter for `unique_ptr`, but that's not possible.

How should I define and handle `data`?

Comment: Interesting related read: [Towards a better allocator model](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1330701318745&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.open-std.org%2Fjtc1%2Fsc22%2Fwg21%2Fdocs%2Fpapers%2F2005%2Fn1850.pdf&ei=A-RQT-DXBeXA0QGJqqXFDQ&usg=AFQjCNFS07GH0af749GIyOIjE-QCc-K7dw&sig2=hBWQcfg-EUOmH2d8UI5UuQ). This is a particular case where the type of the deleter being part of the type breaks the use of `unique_ptr` with different deleter types by a single function... My recommendation: use `shared_ptr` as it performs type erasure on the deleter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make the custom deleter take a run-time value!

```
struct MyCustomDeleter
{
   MemoryType type;
   template <typename T>
   void operator()(T* value) const
   {
      switch (type)
      {
         case MemoryType::heap:
             delete[] value;
             break;
         case MemoryType::shm:
             unmap_from_shm(value);
             break;
         // etc.
      }
   }
};

...

std::unique_ptr<T, MyCustomDeleter> ptr (new T[size], 
                                         MyCustomDeleter{MemoryType::heap});
```

Comment: I used a solution similar to the one you proposed to solve my problem. Anyway my piece of code looks really ugly... I'm thinking about asking a new question in the next few days on how to actually implement this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about `std::unique_ptr`, but you can use `std::shared_ptr`. Its custom deleter doesn't depend on class template parameter.

Comment: This works but has additional overhead beyond what's necessary for a version of `unique_ptr` that does type erasure on the deleter. The extra increments and decrements in maintaining the reference count  probably wouldn't matter, but it's thread-safe increments and decrements. Still, better to use this in a first pass than write your own smart pointer up front, before you know it matters.

Comment: @bames53: In the case it matters I would choose a custom deleter as KennyTM proposed, probably a bit modified to take a functor.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to KennyTm's good answer, another possibility is to use a function pointer as your deleter, and then supply different functions at run time:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(void*)> Ptr;
void delete_global(void*);
void delete_heap(void*);
// etc.

Ptr get(/* whatever */)
{
    if ( ... )
       return Ptr(data, delete_global);
    if (... )
       return Ptr(data, delete_heap);

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a shared `shared_ptr<>` you can choose the deleter at runtime. As long as you don't copy/... the `shared_ptr` it should behave the same as a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Of course, part of the value of `unique_ptr` is that it prevents you from accidentally making copies.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own smart pointer with a deleter you choose:

```
enum DataPointerType
{
    Stack,
    Dynamic,
    SharedMem,
    ...
};

template <class T>
class DataPointer
{
public:
    DataPointer(T* pointer, DataPointerType type)
        : _ptr(pointer), _type(type)
    { }

    ~DataPointer()
    {
        switch (type) {
        case Stack: break;
        case Dynamic: delete _ptr; _ptr = nullptr; break;
        ...
        }
    }

    T& operator*() { return *_ptr; }
    const T& operator*() const { return *ptr; }

    T* operator->() { return _ptr; }
    const T* operator->() const { return ptr; }

private:
   T* _ptr;
    DataPointerType _type;

    // Prevent copying and destruction, dangerous
    DataPointer(const DataPointer& other);
    DataPointer& operator=(const DataPointer& other);
};
```